# Missing factor of 1/2 in the definition of light intensity

Tags: optics

The light field can be written as $E=A \cos\theta$ where $\theta=kz+wt$ is the phase of light wave. 
What we measure or see is the intensity which is the square of the light field

$$I=E^2=A^2 \cos^2\theta$$

Can anyone explain   why most of the textbooks directly show $\ I=E^2=A^2 \cos^2\theta=A^2$ with the reason the phase is changing very fast.

I am confused  why the fast change results in  $\ I=A^2$ rather than $\ I=(1/2)A^2$.

Comment: I don't understand your symbols and especially what $\theta$ is?

Comment: Are you sure that it is written A^2 [cos(θ)]^2 =A^2 ? Well, I don't know what you saw in the book, but the light wave is usually represented as a complex function,  Aexp[i(kr - ωt)], s.t. of course  I = |A|^2

Comment: Please post a link to the original source.  I suspect you've lost the imaginary part (as @Sofia suggests), thus missing the step where the phase drops out.

Comment: Hi, @ Rob Jeffries. θ=kz+wt is the phase of light wave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in that the angular average $\langle \cos^2 \theta \rangle = 1/2$; the simplest way to see this is to take the average of the trigonometric identity $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$, and use the fact that $\langle \cos^2 \theta \rangle = \langle \sin^2 \theta \rangle$. Thus, if your textbook defined the irradiance as $I\equiv \langle \mathbf E^2(\theta)\rangle$, where the electric field $\mathbf E(\theta) = \mathbf E_0 \cos \theta$, then the correct equation is:
$$ I= \frac12 \mathbf E_0^2 $$

However, as Sofia mentioned in the comments, it is also common to represent electromagnetic fields in a complex notation $\mathbf{\tilde E}(\theta) = \mathbf {\tilde E}_0 e^{i\theta}$ to simplify calculations, where the *physical field* is understood to be the real part $\mathbf{E(\theta)} = \text{Re}\big\{\mathbf{\tilde{E}}(\theta)\big\}$. In this notation, the irradiance is usually defined as $I \equiv \langle \mathbf{\tilde E}^*\!\!(\theta)\cdot\mathbf{\tilde E}(\theta) \rangle$, in which case you get:
$$ I = \left|\mathbf{\tilde E}_0\right|^2$$

Comment: @ jabirali. I got it. Cheer~

Answer (score 1):

I would say: do not worry about the 1/2, the only thing you need to know
is that it is proportional to the *square* of the field. You probably do
not want to get really quantitative, so the factor 1/2 does not really
matter.

*If* you really want to get quantitative, then you should avoid the word
“intensity”, and be more specific about what you mean. Is
it the [Poynting vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector)?
The [irradiance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irradiance)?
The [radiance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiance)?
The [radiant intensity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiant_intensity)?
“Intensity” is pretty vague. From the context, it sounds like you mean
irradiance on a plane perpendicular to the Poynting vector. But when an
textbook author uses this term, it generally means that he/she does not
want to get into exact radiometric definitions. Only to convey the
general idea that your eye/detector only cares about the square of the
field.

BTW, you are right in that averaging cos<sup>2</sup>(θ) over θ yields 1/2.

Answer (score 0):

I like to explain this in a simple way.This  example might give you some feeling about intensity.
consider a single bulb glowing it has some intensity,say "I" and you turn on the second bulb now the intensity has become twice than before i.e. "2I"

And more technically it is;  power transferred per unit area.

Comment: @ mubasshir khan, Thank you for your vivid explanation!